# How do I properly sort an array of objects in descending order and search for them in java?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, object

I am a 2nd year student at a local university and I am currently taking a computer programming class. I do quite well in my programming class, although generally I do come to problems. Our professor has given us some incomplete algorithms that he wants us to finish as another diagnostic test. He had told us beforehand that we must do it without using shortcuts, meaning I cannot use comparators, I can only use basic sorting algorithms such as bubble, insertion, selection and merge sort, and I can only use binary or linear search.

I've been given an incomplete file designed to sort students and their marks. A particular problem that I've been coming up with is the sorting algorithm and the searching algorithm that I need to create. Our lecturer has given us some testing material to see if our algorithms work. Surprisingly, mine didn't. I have tried all types of sorting algorithms, but for some reason the test says that the algorithm failed. How do I solve this predicament.

OS: windows 7,
Java Workbench: Eclipse

Here is the code for the algorithm. I apologize if it appears to be quite messy.
This is the sorting algorihtm at the moment. The supposed design(by my professor) was that the array would be sorted in descending order.

```
    public static void sort(Student[] students) {
    if(students == null)
        return;
    for(int i=0;i<students.length-2;i++){
        Student temp = students[i];
        for(int k=i+1;k<students.length-1;k++){
            Student temp2= students[k];
            int result = temp2.compareTo(temp);
            if(result > 0){
                students[k] = temp;
                students[i] = temp2;
            }
        }
    }


}
```

here is the code for the searching algorithm. Again, the supposed design is that it would be able to search for a student's given name and family name using the string "name". The algorithm is to be made in a way such that it would ignore the formatting of the name such as "lastname firstname" and "firstname lastname" and it would ignore capital letters. Again, apologize for the messy work.

```
    public static int search(Student[] students, String name) {
    if(students == null || students.length == 0)
        return -1;
            for(int i=0;i<students.length;i++){
                name.toLowerCase();
                if(name.compareTo(students[i].getGivenName().toLowerCase()+" "+students[i].getFamilyName().toLowerCase()) == 0 || name.compareTo(students[i].getFamilyName().toLowerCase()+" "+students[i].getGivenName().toLowerCase()) == 0)
                    return 1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

So, all in all, in case you skipped to the end, my question is: what did I do wrong with my sorting algorithm, and is there a better, simpler way to shorten the searching algorithm while still working properly

EDIT: here are the testing algorithms for the sorting and searching algorithm respectively. The test sorting algorithm can follow the sorting algorithm I made, but for some reason it doesn't pass the boolean conditions the professor has made.

```
    public void testSort() throws OutOfRangeException, FileNotFoundException {
    Student[] students = new Student[6];
    students[0] = new Student("joey", "mitchel", new int[]{42,51,64,70,81});
    students[1] = new Student("Sandy", "luchel", new int[]{64,51,64,70,81});
    students[2] = new Student("Sandy", "luchel", new int[]{42,51,64,70,81});
    students[3] = new Student("amanda", "jones", new int[]{95,51,64,70,81});
    students[4] = new Student("Susane", "Louis", new int[]{42,51,64,70,81});
    students[5] = new Student("Samuel", "jones", new int[]{95,51,64,70,81});


    StudentSearcherSorter.sort(students);
    for(int i=0; i<students.length - 1; i++) {
        boolean b1 = students[i].total() > students[i+1].total();
        boolean b2 = false;
        boolean b3 = false;
        if(b1 == false && students[i].total() == students[i+1].total())
            b2 = students[i].getFamilyName().compareTo(students[i+1].getFamilyName()) < 0;
        if(b2 == false && students[i].total() == students[i+1].total() && students[i].getFamilyName().compareTo(students[i+1].getFamilyName()) == 0)
            b3 = students[i].getGivenName().compareTo(students[i+1].getGivenName()) < 0;
        assertTrue(b1 || b2 || b3);
    }
}
```

and the searching test algorithm. I am not sure what is wrong, although generally, It might have to do with the way I handled the code for the searching algorithm.

```
    public void testSearch() throws FileNotFoundException, OutOfRangeException {
    Student[] students = new Student[6];
    students[0] = new Student("joey", "mitchel", new int[]{42,51,64,70,81});
    students[1] = new Student("Sandy", "luchel", new int[]{64,51,64,70,81});
    students[2] = new Student("Sandy", "luchel", new int[]{42,51,64,70,81});
    students[3] = new Student("amanda", "jones", new int[]{95,51,64,70,81});
    students[4] = new Student("Susane", "Louis", new int[]{42,51,64,70,81});
    students[5] = new Student("Samuel", "jones", new int[]{95,51,64,70,81});


    for(int i=0; i<students.length; i++) {
        assertTrue(StudentSearcherSorter.search(students, students[i].getGivenName().toUpperCase()+" "+students[i].getFamilyName()) >= 0);
        assertTrue(StudentSearcherSorter.search(students, students[i].getFamilyName()+" "+students[i].getGivenName().toUpperCase()) >= 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: For your searching algo, `Strings` are immutable. I.e it should be `name = name.toLowerCase();`

Comment: If I were doing this as part of a real program, rather than as an exercise, I would write a Comparator<String> to compare strings in descending order ignoring case. Use that Comparator in Arrays.sort and Arrays.binarySearch.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan, this would not teach the student anything about sorting and searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the sorting, in the original version, the code does not compare the last two elements in the `students` array.

```
public static void sort(Student[] students) {
    if(students == null)
        return;
```

Your upper bound of the loop should be `students.length - 1`, so the last value
of `i` would be `students.length - 2`.

```
    // for(int i=0;i<students.length-2;i++){
    for(int i=0;i<students.length-1;i++){
        Student temp = students[i];
```

Likewise, the upper bound of this loop should be `students.length`, so the last value
of `k` would be `stidents.length - 1`. Alternatively, in both cases you can
replace `<` with `<=`.

```
        // for(int k=i+1;k<students.length-1;k++){
        for(int k=i+1;k<students.length;k++){
            Student temp2= students[k];
            int result = temp2.compareTo(temp);
            if(result > 0){
                students[k] = temp;
                students[i] = temp2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I have used the changes that you have suggested, but it seems to have failed the test again. Just in case, though, I have edited my question so that you can see what the program is testing for.

Comment: @user3101890 Show Student.compareTo and check is does the same comparisons as the ones in testSort.